# Find the minimum value of $f'/f$

Tags: derivatives, applications

> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a function . Suppose the function $f$ is differentiable . $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and satisfies
> $$ f''(x)-4f'(x)+4f(x)\ge { e }^{ 2x },\qquad x\in [0,1] $$ .
> If the function
> $g(x)={ e }^{ -2x }f(x)$ at $x=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } $ then $\min\left( \frac { f'(x) }{ f(x) }  \right) ,x\in \left( 0,\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) $

My attempt

$f''(x)-4f'(x)+4f(x)-{ e }^{ 2x }\ge 0\\ { e }^{ -x }f''(x)-4({ e }^{ -x }f'(x)-{ e }^{ -x }f(x))-{ e }^{ x }\ge 0\\ { e }^{ -x }f''(x)-4\frac { d }{ dx } \left( { e }^{ -x }f(x) \right) \ge 0$

Now I am not able to select any increasing or decreasing function Please help

Comment: I think you need to correct something. What does $g(x)$ have to do with anything, and why at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: $g'(x)={ e }^{ -2x }f'(x)-2{ e }^{ -2x }f(x)\\ g'\left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) =0\\ \Rightarrow f'\left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) =f'\left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) $

Comment: can we use anything out of this

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$y=f(x)$

1. Solve $y''-4y'+4 y ={ e }^{ 2x }$ which is a second order non-homogeneous ODE.
   The solution is: $\boxed{y(x) = c_1 e^{2x} + c_2e^{2x} + \frac12e^{2x}x^2}$. Tip: Find the solution of the characteristic polynomial to get a partial solution. You can solve the homogeneous using undetermined coefficients.
2. Find the derivative of $h'(x) = \left( \frac{f'}{f} \right)' = \left( \frac{4e^{2x}+e^{2x}x^2+e^{2x}x}{e^{2x}\:+e^{2x}\:+\:\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}x^2} \right)' = \frac{2\left(-e^{4x}x^2+4e^{4x}\right)}{\left(4e^{2x}+e^{2x}x^2\right)^2}$
3. Find the critical points (where $h'(x) = 0$ or not defined) to spot the global minimum. You will notice that $$\boxed{\mathrm{Minimum}\left(-2\sqrt{3},\:-\frac{1}{16}\right)}$$

Comment: there is ineuqality

Comment: Greater or equal. You let the equality, in order to solve the ODE and find $f(x)$.

Comment: You could reduce the problem to $g(x)$ terms, by substituting, but this is straight enough.

Answer (score -1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

$$e^{-2x}f''(x) - 4e^{-2x}f'(x)+4e^{-2x}f(x) = \Bigr(e^{-2x}f(x)\Bigr)''$$

by binomial expansion (product rule) which means

$$g''(x) \geq 1$$

Also, you can prove that

$$\frac{f'}{f} = 2 + \frac{g'}{g}$$

Comment: how you got the second the second relation @Ninad